# Order of compare commits feature in GitKraken

Tags: git, gitkraken

In GitKraken you can compare two commits by by selecting them in the graph.  Only the order seems to be fixed.  I want to select the order.  e.g., I want to see how branchB changed from branchA, not the other way around.  Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure tbh. You can always think about the changes as opposite. Deleted is actually added, etc.

Comment: thats what i've been doing.  but prefer to ditch the extra cognitive load